# Cannot find array

Tags: java, processing

I get the error "cannot find anything named coordinates" at line 110:

```
 System.out.println(coordinates[k][l]);
```

when trying to run this:

```
import TUIO.*;
TuioProcessing tuioClient;

int cols = 15, rows = 10;
boolean[][] states = new boolean[cols][rows];
int videoScale = 50;

// these are some helper variables which are used
// to create scalable graphical feedback
int x, y, i, j;
float cursor_size = 15;
float object_size = 60;
float table_size = 760;
float scale_factor = 1;
PFont font;

boolean verbose = false; // print console debug messages
boolean callback = true; // updates only after callbacks



void setup(){
  size(500,500);
noCursor();

  noStroke();
  fill(0);

  // periodic updates
  if (!callback) {
    frameRate(60); //<>//
    loop();
  } else noLoop(); // or callback updates 

  font = createFont("Arial", 18);
  scale_factor = height/table_size;

  // finally we create an instance of the TuioProcessing client
  // since we add "this" class as an argument the TuioProcessing class expects
  // an implementation of the TUIO callback methods in this class (see below)
  tuioClient  = new TuioProcessing(this);

}
void draw(){
  // Begin loop for columns
  for (int k = 0; k < cols; k++) {
    // Begin loop for rows
    for (int l = 0; l < rows; l++) {

      // Scaling up to draw a rectangle at (x,y)
      int x = k*videoScale;
      int y = l*videoScale;

      fill(255);
      stroke(0);

      String[][] coordinates = new String[cols][rows]; 

for (int i = 0; i < cols; i++) {
  for (int j = 0; j < rows; j++) { 

 coordinates[i][j] = String.valueOf((char)(i+65)) + String.valueOf(j).toUpperCase();

  }
}

      //check if coordinates are within a box (these are mouse x,y but could be fiducial x,y)
      //simply look for bounds (left,right,top,bottom)
      if( (mouseX >= x &&  mouseX <= x + videoScale) && //check horzontal
          (mouseY >= y &&  mouseY <= y + videoScale)){
        //coordinates are within a box, do something about it
       System.out.println(coordinates[k][l]); 
        //you can keep track of the boxes states (contains x,y or not) 
        states[k][l] = true;

        if(mousePressed) println(k+"/"+l);

      }else{

        states[k][l] = false;

      }


      rect(x,y,videoScale,videoScale); 
    }
  }

   textFont(font,18*scale_factor);
  float obj_size = object_size*scale_factor; 
  float cur_size = cursor_size*scale_factor; 

  ArrayList<TuioObject> tuioObjectList = tuioClient.getTuioObjectList();
  for (int i=0;i<tuioObjectList.size();i++) {
     TuioObject tobj= tuioObjectList.get(i);
     stroke(0);
     fill(0,0,0);
     pushMatrix();
     translate(tobj.getScreenX(width),tobj.getScreenY(height));
     rotate(tobj.getAngle());
     rect(-obj_size/2,-obj_size/2,obj_size,obj_size);
     popMatrix();
     fill(255);
     text(""+tobj.getSymbolID(), tobj.getScreenX(width), tobj.getScreenY(height));
     System.out.println(tobj.getSymbolID ()+ " " + tobj.getX());

     if( ( tobj.getX()>= x &&  tobj.getX() <= x + videoScale) && //check horzontal
          (tobj.getY() >= y &&  tobj.getY() <= y + videoScale)){
        //coordinates are within a box, do something about it
       System.out.println(coordinates[k][l]); 


   }

}
}
// --------------------------------------------------------------
// these callback methods are called whenever a TUIO event occurs
// there are three callbacks for add/set/del events for each object/cursor/blob type
// the final refresh callback marks the end of each TUIO frame
// called when an object is added to the scene

/* void addTuioObject(TuioObject tobj) {
  if (verbose) println("add obj "+tobj.getSymbolID()+" ("+tobj.getSessionID()+") "+tobj.getX()+" "+tobj.getY()+" "+tobj.getAngle());
}

 // called when an object is moved
void updateTuioObject (TuioObject tobj) {
  if (verbose) println("set obj "+tobj.getSymbolID()+" ("+tobj.getSessionID()+") "+tobj.getX()+" "+tobj.getY());
}

// called when an object is removed from the scene
void removeTuioObject(TuioObject tobj) {
  if (verbose) println("del obj "+tobj.getSymbolID()+" ("+tobj.getSessionID()+")");
}
*/

// --------------------------------------------------------------
// called at the end of each TUIO frame
void refresh(TuioTime frameTime) {
  if (verbose) println("frame #"+frameTime.getFrameID()+" ("+frameTime.getTotalMilliseconds()+")");
  if (callback) redraw();
}
```

I don't understand why since I declared it line 57:

```
String[][] coordinates = new String[cols][rows];
```

Anyone knows why ? Should I declare it in a different way to make it accessible everywhere ?

Thanks for your help

Comment: We do not have the benefit of seeing line numbers in your code. If you're referencing them, please point out the specific lines for us.

Comment: Sorry I added the lines

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're declaring your `coordinates` variable inside your first nested for loop, so it's only in scope during the execution of that loop. It's recreated every time the loop iterates.

But you're trying to access that variable after that loop exits. At that point, the `coordinates` variable is out of scope, so you get that error.

You have to refactor your code so that `coordinates` is in scope when you access it.

In other words, this won't work:

```
for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++){
   String test = "xyz";
}

println(test);
```

Since the `test` variable is only visible inside the loop, you can't use it outside that loop. Instead you have to do something like this:

```
for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++){
   String test = "xyz";
   println(test);
}
```

Or this:

```
String test = "abc";
for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++){
   test = "xyz";
}

println(test);
```

Which approach you take depends on what exactly you want your code to do.

Comment: I modified it as in your second example, but now I get the error at the same line: "ArrayOutOfBoundException: 15"

Comment: @MatthiasGrahamSlick That's a separate problem. You need to really understand what your code is doing: what is the size of the array? Why are you accessing an index that's larger than that? If you're still stuck, post an updated [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) (try to keep it as small as possible, like my examples) as a new question.